# NPM behind a proxy : can't download any packages

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy, http-proxy

I am working on a server that has access to the Internet through a proxy. I can't neither access proxy configuration nor change it.
These are the options of `.npmrc` :

```
https-proxy = "https://10.1.0.254:8080/" 
proxy = "http://10.1.0.254:8080/" 
strict-ssl = false
```

When I try to download a package I get this error prompt :

```
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! syscall write
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/bower failed, reason: write EPROTO 139954307135424:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-02-15T15_26_16_616Z-debug-0.log
```

I have access to `https://registry.npmjs.org/` with a web browser through this proxy and the server can resolve the name. I mention that APT works perfectly.

I'm running out of ideas on how to get this working. Any ideas ?

I tried to remove `.npmrc` configuration and to rely only on system proxy definition. I tried to update npm and also to find other occurence of this problem here.

**EDIT :**
I bypassed the proxy and still get the exact same issue. I can ping `https://registry.npmjs.org/` without the proxy and still can't download a package.

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove the `.npmrc`, try to add this:

```
ssl-protocol=TLSv1.2
```

Or Alternatively try using a different registry by adding the following line to your .npmrc file::

```
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunatly, it did not solve my problem.